# iOS app communicate with Laravel webapp

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, laravel

I’m working on a project based on an iOS app (native) who use a webapp (Laravel framework) to communicate.
For exemple, ios user should use Laravel login to use the application.
The laravel part of the project is done and work good on a computer (login,register etc…)
But now i’m thinking how will i communicate with my futur ios App and my webapp using laravel framework. I dont know any ways to do that, maybe i need a special framwork on my ios app ?

I have no idea, can you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The normal way - create a json api for your app to consume

Comment: but how send json content from ios to the laravel api?

Comment: Not an Objective-C fan, but basically you will just be making a standard http post/get request. A google for IOS post request brings up plenty of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a loaded question....  My personal preference is to set up a set of API controllers so you can control them independently and version them.

1) Create a sub-set of controllers @ `/app/controllers/api/v1`
2) Give them all a namespace of `api/v1`

```
<?php namespace api\v1;
```

3) Import whatever classes you need into the new namespace

```
<?php namespace api\v1;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Usage;
use Auth;
```

4) Install an [oAuth2 package](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel)
5) Set up routes that generate and validate tokens and place your protected routes in a route group.  (my example below.)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'apiErrors'], function()
{

    Route::post('accessToken', function()
    {

        return AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();

    });

    Route::group(['before' => 'oauth|setUser'], function()
    {

        Route::resource('usages', 'api\v1\UsagesController');
        Route::resource('connections', 'api\v1\ConnectionsController');
        Route::resource('users', 'api\v1\UsersController');

    });

});
```

6) Set up your new api controllers to return data in a manner that a mobile app can use (JSON)

```
public function index()
{

    $usages = Usage::with('device.model.manufacturer')
                    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->get();

    return Response::json($usages, $this->responseCode, $this->accessControl);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your complete answer ! but i have done an simple API controller without oAuth2 package. My controller for the moment just return true or false if login is okay and it works good.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your complete answer ! but i have done an simple API controller without oAuth2 package. My controller for the moment just return true or false if login is okay and it works good. here my code for other people...

```
public function trylogin() {


         if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'))) || Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
            return Response::json(array('status' => 'OK'));
        } else {
            return Response::json(array('status' => 'FAIL'));
            }    
}
```

here my api routes

```
Route::resource('api/v1', 'ApiController');
Route::get('api/v1_hello', 'ApiController@sayhello');
Route::get('api/v1_login', 'ApiController@trylogin')
```

what do you think about security managment ? i can make my own token system validation on ios ?

**EDIT**

i finally found a solution, here the function in my ApiController :
you just need to send to your api from iOS the token generate by Facebook or Google connexion. and in my case add a network parameter.

```
 public function registerOrLoginFromSocialNetWorkV1(){      

    if (Input::get('email') && Input::get('sn_id')) {
        //sn = social network
        if (User::where('email','=', Input::get('email'))->count() != 0) {
            $user = User::where('email','=', Input::get('email'))->first();
             $user->fb_id = Input::get('sn_id');
             $user->save();
              //return 'email already used';

        }
        else{

            if (User::where('fb_id','=', Input::get('sn_id'))->count() == 0) {
                $user = new User;
                $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
                $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
                $user->username = Input::get('username');
                $user->email = Input::get('email');
                $user->fb_id = Input::get('sn_id');
                $user->fk_role = 3;
                $user->yearofbirth = Input::get('birthday');

                //$user->yearofbirth = substr($me['birthday'],6,9);

                if (Input::get('sex') == 'male') {
                    $user->sex = 1;
                }
                else{
                    $user->sex = 0;
                }


                $user->save();

                Userslog::log('api_register_social_network');

            }
            else{
                $user = User::where('fb_id','=', Input::get('sn_id'))->first();
                if (!$user->yearofbirth){
                     $user->yearofbirth = Input::get('birthday');
                     $user->save();

                }

            }

        }

            //dd($user);
            Auth::login($user);




            $follows = Follow::where('user_id','=',$user->id)->get();

            return Response::json(array('user' => $user,'follows' => $follows));
    }
    else{
         return 'error';

    }




}
```

Comment: How can I use oauth2 package in Laravel? The doc isn't clear. Can you help me here?

Comment: use this : https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel
if you have a question, create post !

Comment: I need to implement my own oauth service not consume!

Comment: @KbirMhrjn I know it's old comment but for those landing here I think need to check this for creating service: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport